# Is there a way to detect if a PHPUnit test is running in background?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, tdd

PHPUnit has [two special annotations](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.runTestsInSeparateProcesses) to indicate a test should run in a background process: a class annotation `@runTestsInSeparateProcesses` that affects all tests in the current class, and a test annotation `@runInSeparateProcess` that affects the current test.

This is useful in some cases when the tested class needs to print some output, so it would not mess up with PHPUnit's own output.

So, here's my question: is the TestCase class aware of this fact? Does it know when it's running on background? If so, is there a method to detect it?

I'm looking for something like `$this->isRunningOnBackground()`.

I did not find anything about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsing PHPUnit's source code, I found a boolean protected property in TestCase class `$runTestInSeparateProcess` that is set to true when the annotation is present. There's a `$runClassInSeparateProcess` as well, but it's set to private, so you won't access it in a child class context.

We can detect if a test is running on background by just checking `if ($this->runTestInSeparateProcess) {...}` inside setUp() or tearDown().